# virtualmin installation error

Tags: centos

I am using Centos 5 64 bin os and try to install virtualmin by /bin/sh install.sh
installation process is start 
After few sec i got flowing error and installation stop working
"-Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
-Error: Missing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 is needed by package httpd-devel-2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3.i386 (installed)"
please help me

Comment: Administration panels are off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using 64 bits OS, it's safely remove `httpd-devel.i386` package:

```
# yum remove httpd-devel-2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3.i386
```

and try again.

Comment: after you remove htt.. process is continue still there is no error i update you after complete the process thanks!

Comment: Installation is completed...